# Windows form duplicates itself

Tags: c#

After clicking a button that leads to the form the form displays but then another duplicate of the form appears.I only call the form once when a certain condition is true. What could be the reason for this?

```
if (selectedGame.NumOfPlayerShortForGame == 0)
{
   bl.UpdateGamePlayerTurn(myGame.GameID, username);
   GoToPlayingScreen();
}
private void GoToPlayingScreen()
{
   frmPlayingScreen playingScreen = new frmPlayingScreen(myGame, username);
   this.Hide();
   playingScreen.Show();
}
private void timerUpdateBindings_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      timerUpdateBindings.Stop();
      if (counter == 0)
      {
          UpdateBindings();
          //myGame = bl.GetUserGame(username);
           if (myGame != null)
           {
              if (bl.GetRemainingPlayers(myGame.GameID) == 0)
               {
                        counter++;
                        GoToPlayingScreen();
                }
           }                
      }
            timerUpdateBindings.Start();
}
```

Comment: you need to post some code....preferably stripped down but showing behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any source code, I can only guess. However, it sounds like you might have the old favorite problem of the "Forgotten Event Handler". You may have an event handler on some event that opens the same form as the code that triggers the event, resulting in two copies of the form being opened.

You should post your code (trimmed down to the important parts if at all possible) so we can provide more useful help.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in the form's constructor - you'll be able to step through to see where the form is being instantiated.

Obvious question: are you calling GoToPlayingScreen() twice?  I'm not sure what you're doing with the first IF statement (it's not in a method).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this little nugget is the problem

```
if (selectedGame.NumOfPlayerShortForGame == 0)
{
   bl.UpdateGamePlayerTurn(myGame.GameID, username);
   GoToPlayingScreen();
}
```

because on initialisation you probably won't have any players playing the game so selectedGame.NumOfPlayerShortForGame would be equal to zero, maybe.

As Charlie Salts suggested, try setting some breakpoints to see the flow of program execution. Set breakpoints on any place that GoToPlayingScreen() is being called. That will pause the execution of the program for you when the methods are being called.

If the execution pauses only once but you still see two game screens, try setting breakpoints on 
   playingScreen.Show();

and see where you are calling this. Try using the autos tool to see if counter is being tested twice for being equal to zero. I don't see how it's possible, but it's just another suggestion in case. You know code, it works in magical ways sometimes.